# why when using position "fixed" in chakra ui the navbar is protrude out of screen and change width size

Tags: reactjs, css-position, chakra-ui

when add position fixed in navbar the navbar **size** is changed and **get out of place**, **overlapping** with below

the result I need is navbar **stay in place** and take position **fixed** at **top** of page,
and don't **overlapping with below**

LayoutRoot Component

here is layout Root it it's two columns and 1 row

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { Grid, GridItem, Flex, Box, Container, Spacer } from "@chakra-ui/react";

import Navbar from "./Navbar";

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "../pages/Home";
import User from "../pages/User";
import LeftSidebar from "./LeftSidebar";


import i18next from "i18next";

function LayoutRoot() {
  // When Language Changed The dir attribute in body tag
  // will change direction based on language.
  //for ex. if it ar it wil start from right to left and vice versa.
  i18next.on("languageChanged", (locale) => {
    let direction = i18next.dir(locale);

    document.body.dir = direction;
  });

  const [navSize, changeNavSize] = useState("small");

  return (
    <>
      {/* ===== Grid Layout ===== */}

      <Grid
        templateColumns="repeat(5, minmax(100px, auto))"
        templateRows="repeat(2, 1fr)"
        // gap={5}
        h="200px"
      >
        {/* ===== Start Left Sidebar ===== */}

        <GridItem
          colSpan={1}
          rowSpan={2}
          w={navSize == "small" ? "100px" : "200px"}
          display={{ sm: "none", lg: "grid" }}
          backdropFilter="auto"
          backdropBlur="22px"
          transition="all 0.3s ease-in-out"
          p="6"

        >
          <LeftSidebar
            small="small"
            large="large"
            navSize={navSize}
            changeNavSize={changeNavSize}
          />
        </GridItem>
        {/* ===== End Left Sidebar ===== */}    

        {/* ===== Start Navbar ===== */}

        <GridItem colSpan="4" zIndex="99">
          <Box position="fixed" w="100%">
            <Navbar />
          </Box>
        </GridItem>

        {/* ===== End Navbar ===== */}

        {/* ===== Start Right Sidebar =====  */}
        <GridItem
          colSpan={{ sm: "5", lg: "4" }}
          backdropFilter="auto"
          backdropBlur="22px"
          boxShadow="xl"
          p="6"
        >
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home />}></Route>
              <Route path="/user" element={<User />}></Route>
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </GridItem>
        {/* ===== End Right Sidebar =====  */}
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}

export default LayoutRoot;
```

Navbar Component

```
import React from "react";

import {
  Box,
  Avatar,
  Menu,
  MenuButton,
  MenuItem,
  MenuList,
  IconButton,
  Button,
  Grid,
  GridItem,
  Icon,
  Image,
  useColorMode,
  Container,
  Flex

} from "@chakra-ui/react";

import { FaBell, FaCog } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FaGlobe } from "react-icons/fa6";
import {
  HamburgerIcon,
  AddIcon,
  ExternalLinkIcon,
  ChevronDownIcon,
  SunIcon,
  MoonIcon,
} from "@chakra-ui/icons";

import i18next from "i18next";


function Navbar() {
  const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode()

  return (
    <>
      <Grid
        templateColumns={"repeat(5, 1fr)"}
        display={{ sm: "none", md: "grid" }}
       
      >

        <GridItem colSpan="1">
          <Flex w="100%" h="100px" alignItems="center" >
            {colorMode === "light" ? <Image src="/darkLogo.svg" w="200px"/> : <Image src="/lightLogo.svg" w="200px"/>}
          </Flex>
        </GridItem>

        <GridItem colSpan="4">
          <Flex  w="100%" h="100px" justify="flex-end" alignItems="center">

            <Avatar name="Dan Abrahmov" src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20190710/ourmid/pngtree-user-vector-avatar-png-image_1541962.jpg" />

            <Icon as={FaBell} fontSize={"22"} marginX={"11"} />

            <Icon as={FaCog} fontSize={"22"} marginX={"11"} />

            <Menu display="flex" alignItems="center" h="70px" isLazy  marginX={"11"}>

              <MenuButton as={Button} bg="none" fontSize="22" rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />}>
                <Icon as={FaGlobe} />
              </MenuButton>

              <MenuList zIndex="2">
                <MenuItem onClick={() => i18next.changeLanguage("ar")}>
                  العربية
                </MenuItem>

                <MenuItem onClick={() => i18next.changeLanguage("en")}>
                  English
                </MenuItem>
              </MenuList>
            </Menu>

            <Button onClick={toggleColorMode}>
              {colorMode == 'dark' ? <SunIcon color="orange.400" /> : <MoonIcon color="blue.400" />}
            </Button>
          </Flex>
        </GridItem>
      </Grid>

      <Box
        h="70px"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="flex-start"
        display={{ sm: "flex", md: "none" }}
        pos="fixed"
      >
        <Menu>
          <MenuButton
            as={IconButton}
            aria-label="Options"
            icon={<HamburgerIcon />}
            variant="outline"
          />
          <MenuList>
            <MenuItem icon={<AddIcon />} command="⌘T">
              New Tab
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem icon={<ExternalLinkIcon />} command="⌘N">
              New Window
            </MenuItem>
          </MenuList>
        </Menu>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```